Case deletion effect in residual sum of squares
How do we prove the following formula for the residual sum of squares when the case indexed by $J$ is deleted from the data, i.e.,
$$s^2_{(J)} = s^2 - e_J^T (I_k - H_J)^{-1} e_J\,,$$
where $s^2$ is the residual sum of squares without the deleted case, e_J are the residuals for the case J, $I_k$ is the identity matrix and $H_J$ is the $J$-th diagonal element of the hat matrix.
A sketch of the proof is given in eq. (4.3) of http://www.csam.or.kr/journal/view.html?doi=10.5351/CSAM.2016.23.3.231. However, I do not know how to go from the second to the third line in this proof.
